# Rails form builder with admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, formbuilder

The code below works well to create new transactions on the Invoice show view. It however doesn't work when in admin namespace. i.e /admin/invoices/1/ but works on /invoices/1/

show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@invoice, @invoice.transactions.build]) do |form| %>
....
transactions form input
```

routes.rb

```
resources :invoices do
  resources :transactions
end
```

Comment: What is the the value of form's `action` attribute in rendered view?

Comment: /invoices/1/transactions

Answer (score 1):

When calling `form_for` in a namespace route like `/admin/invoices/1/`, Rails will  automatically append `admin` to your route. In other words, `form_for([@invoice, @invoice.transactions.build])` would POST to a route like `/admin/invoice/:id/transactions/` rather than `/invoice/:id/transactions/`.

To fix, explicitly set the URL of the form and use a route helper method to infer the correct route:

```
form_for(@invoice, url: invoice_transaction_url(@invoice.id))
```

Note that you may need to replace `invoice_transaction_url` with the correct route. Use `rake routes` to find the helper method that corresponds to the desired controller POST action.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. My action url is 

 /invoices/1/transactions

It seems its not being appended. I'm not sure if this is correct, After submitting i get the "uninitialized constant TransactionsController" error and i end up at  /invoices/1/transactions instead of 
admin/invoices/1/transactions

Comment: What line gives you the `"uninitialized constant TransactionsController"`, is it the `form_for`? Is your transactions controller defined in a namespace?

Comment: Yes its defined in a namespace.

    resources :invoices do
      resources :transactions
    end

    namespace :admin do
       resources :transactions
    end

The error is happening at a URL (/invoices/1/transactions) with no routes defined since Invoices and transactions are only accessed in admin.

Comment: Problem solved

Needed to wrap my route inside an admin namespace and change the form_for to:

` form_for([:admin, @invoice, @invoice.transactions.build ]) do `

Comment: Yes. As per the fine print on https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with :)